# SikuliX 1.0rc3 r903 type() to use normal number instead of Numpad

Tags: java, python, jython, keycode, sikuli

I have a little automation script with SikuliX to maintain a certain flow in a application and I need to press a numeric key (1,2,3...,0).

The problem is that the application doesn't seem to accept Numpad keys and neither accepts a string input of a number;

```
type(Key.NUM1) # Doesn't work
type("1") # Doesn't work
type(Key.1) # Logically gives a parse-error
```

Looking at the [documentation](http://doc.sikuli.org/keys.html) I can't find anything on calling specific key mappings. I've tried to look into the JAVA docs for `java.awt.event.InputEvent` as well, but am not sure how to manipulate it in Sikuli, as they also seem to have changed certain parent methods.

I wonder if I could do something like;

```
type(Key.Code("49")) # Key code 49 for the number "1"
```

Comment: Are you able to type *any* keys into the application using Sikuli?  For example, if you do `type("hello")` does that work?

Comment: Yes I'm in a *typing-field* it works. Sadly when it's in the general environment it doesn't trigger on the *1*-key as the application does when I do it manually.

Comment: You're still not clear.  When you're in a typing field, you can type characters but not numbers?  If you `type("abc123")` you get `abc`?

Comment: I mean that the `currently active application` cannot `receive` the `type()`-command in general. So anything in `type('.123abc_+=...')` works when inside an *input-field* (or *typing-field*), but not when the application needs to receive a key in general (without any specific *area* or *input-field* selected. So what I mean is that when I press `1`,`2`,`z`,`n` etc. normally with my keyboard it triggers certain actions, but not when Sikuli gives those commands with `type()`.

Comment: So *no* keys work in the application.  It may be that the application is grabbing input at too low a level for Sikuli to fake.  If you're on Windows, you might try AutoHotKey and see if that's able to generate synthetic key-presses for you.

Answer (score 1):

type("1") definitely works, I just tried it out

Edit:
Do you get this logmessage when running type("1") ?

[log] TYPE "1"

Comment: Yes it does, but my application doesn't accept it as a "Key". So my question in this case is explicitly; how to call a keyboard key by it's Key-Code :)

Comment: @Allendar why do you say that `type("1")` doesn't work in your question, but then agree with kel that it does work?

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot I agree with kel that it works in *general application*. I use it in other applications very often. I'm stating that typing `1` in the concerning application doesn't work, as it probably blocks virtual string-input. Thus in that case I am wondering if there is a way to call "KeyCodes" specifically in Sikuli.